# boost::geometry svg_mapper, the polygon is not fully saved?

Tags: boost, geometry

I have a simple example where a graph of polygon is created and saved to an svg file. However, the polygon is partially saved only. So how can I resize the graph?

```
#include <string> 
#include <fstream>

#include <boost/geometry.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/point_xy.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/polygon.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/adapted/c_array.hpp>


// Using the boost namespace
using namespace boost::geometry;

// Register the C array points for boost
BOOST_GEOMETRY_REGISTER_C_ARRAY_CS(cs::cartesian)

template <typename Geometry>
void create_svg(std::string const& file_path, Geometry const& geometry, std::string 
                const& style) {
    using PointType = typename point_type<Geometry>::type;
    std::ofstream svg_file(file_path.c_str());
    svg_mapper<PointType> mapper(svg_file, 2000, 2000); 
    mapper.add(geometry);
    mapper.map(geometry, style);
}

int main() {
    model::polygon<model::d2::point_xy<double>, false> polygon;
    double points[][2] = {{0., 0.}, {2., 1.}, {3., 3.}, {-0.5, 0.5}, {0., 0.}};
    append(polygon, points);
    std::string style{"fill-rule:nonzero;fill-opacity:0.5;fill:yellow;stroke:black;stroke-width:2;"};
    create_svg("image.svg", polygon, style);
    return 0;
}
```

The output is like:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems that somehow the scale factor/bounding box get miscalculated.

Using

```
bg::svg_mapper<PointType> mapper(svg_file, 400, 400);
```

works fine. If all coords get scaled at (larger than) integral grid, all is fine.

I tried to isolate any contibuting factor ([integral coordinate type, clockwise orientation polygons, `SameScale = true` template argument for the `svg_mapper`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/71606cc467ff2edb)) but it all seems unrelated. Ubsan did not flag anything. I would report this at the library. Meanwhile, try smaller SVG dimensions to "hide" the issue:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/27dd09deee50a511)**

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

#include <boost/geometry.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/point_xy.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/polygon.hpp>

// Using the boost namespace
namespace bg = boost::geometry;

template <typename Geometry>
void create_svg(std::string const& file_path, Geometry const& geometry,
                std::string const& style)
{
    using PointType = typename bg::point_type<Geometry>::type;
    std::ofstream svg_file(file_path);

    bg::svg_mapper<PointType/*, true*/> mapper(svg_file, 400, 400);
    mapper.add(geometry);
    mapper.map(geometry, style);
}

template <typename T> void check(T& geo) {
    for (std::string reason; !bg::is_valid(geo, reason); bg::correct(geo)) {
        std::cout << "Correcting: " << reason << "\n";
    }
}

int main()
{
    bg::model::polygon<bg::model::d2::point_xy<double>> polygon{
        {{0, 0}, {-.5, .5}, {3, 3}, {2, 1}, {0, 0}}};

    check(polygon);

    std::string style{"fill-rule:nonzero;fill-opacity:0.5;fill:yellow;stroke:"
                      "black;stroke-width:2;"};
    create_svg("image.svg", polygon, style);
}
```

Rendering:

[image]

### BREAKTHROUGH

I just noticed that for me Chrome renders the "weird" SVG as

[image]

I thought is was strange that is is rendered differently from your question.

I just thought to check with Inkscape, and lo and behold, it comes out "normal":

[image]

The x/y rulers seem to indicate correct scaling. So my best theory is that it's a browser-specific limitation that doesn't render "very large" SVG scales well?

Comment: Many thanks! Although I do not know the mechanism behind the problem, smaller scaling works fine so far.

Comment: And I agree with you on that the problem seems render-related. The figure with (400, 400) is rendered well by Chrome on my machine (Ubuntu 16.04), but displayed partially in the default image viewer.